# Custom modular routing PyroCMS

Tags: codeigniter, routes, pyrocms

I have a custom module called **user** located in addons/shared_addons. In my config/routes.php I have...

```
$route['user/admin(:any)?']     = 'admin$1';
$route['user/(:any)?'] = 'user/index/$1';

//and this is my custom route
$route['user/login'] = 'user/login';
```

No matter what I try, it will always give me a 404 error. I'm able to set custom routes in the  system/pyrocms ... but for some reason, the same method is not working for me with shared_addons directory. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you can have a custom module with the title `User` because that's a core module

Comment: Strange, that worked. Didn't think it would be the case. Thanks